# Easy 'create table from view' syntax in mysql?

Tags: mysql, syntax

I want to create a table that's a cache of results from a view. Is there an easy way to automatically define the table from the view's definition, or will I have to cobble it together from `show create table view`?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can do `CREATE TABLE SELECT` from the view to build it. That should duplicate the view's structure as a new table containing all the view's rows.  Here's the [MySQL syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html) for this statement.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_from_view AS    
  SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4,
    col5
  FROM your_view;
```

Note that you will want to be very explicit in your column selections.  It isn't advisable to do a `SELECT *` from the source view. Make sure as well that you have aliases for any calculated or aggregate columns like `COUNT(*), MAX(*), (col1 + col2)`, etc.

Comment: Why isn't it advisable to do `SELECT *`?

Comment: @MartinBurch It is generally _never_ advisable to `SELECT *` in production code, preferring instead to be explicit about the columns retrieved and their order. In the case of a CTAS, you may wish to specify the column order. If you know for certain that you need all columns and they are in the preferred order already, then go ahead with `SELECT *`, but it's better to be explicit and avoid surpirses (like large binary blob columns added by your colleagues, unbeknownst to you)

Comment: Will this table change if the data in table for reference change?

Comment: @Attaroqqi No, once created, this table is entirely disconnected from the original view.

Comment: so the table won't be dynamic like view?

Comment: @Attaroqqi No, you would need to replace the cache table rows on some cache refresh schedule or other event. It could be a scheduled stored procedure call, maybe a trigger from one of the view tables if it rarely changes.

Answer (score 3):

I also found that in the mysqldump output, there are statements that create the view as a table, just before it defines the view. I can parse those out and run them as queries.