# How do I store my 'view' as a permanent table in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and still learning.

Once I've done operations on a table (say table 1) to get a view. How do I translate/convert/store this view into a new permanent table (table 2)? Also, is it possible to store it in the same table (table 1)?

My code is something like this:

```
select `Date`, `Close Price`,
round(avg(`Close Price`) over (order by `date` asc rows 19 preceding), 2) 
as '20 Day MA' 
from table1;  -- this is my view
```

then i'd like table1 or a new table to store this view (the columns 
 **date, close price, 20 day ma**)

**basically,**
Old table: date, close price

New table: date, close price, 20_day_ma

Maybe it's simpler to just add the new column **20_day_ma** but I wouldn't know how to add the new values that rely on the other columns.

**edit:**

So just tried this:

```
DELIMITER $$
-- create table1
drop table if exists table1;

create table table1 as
select STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d-%M-%Y') as `Date`, `Close Price`,
round(avg(`Close Price`) over (order by `date` asc rows 19 preceding), 2) as 
'20 Day MA'
from source_table $$

DELIMITER ;
```

And I constantly get the error: *Commands out of sync*

Comment: Don't store result sets. Create a VIEW! http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-views-mysql.aspx

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately I've to submit an assignment that particularly mentions I create a table to store results.

Comment: Check out this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241922/easy-create-table-from-view-syntax-in-mysql

Comment: Did your teacher really ask you to store results in a new table?

Comment: @JimBuckleyBarret Hey I did try that yesterday but ended up with errors. I guess i should mention that in my question.

Comment: Since you specify `DELIMITER $$`, you should change the delimiter here, too: `drop table if exists table1$$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do 3 things:
1> create a view (youi'll refer to the view as if it was a table)

```
create view my_new_view as
select `Date`, `Close Price`,
round(avg(`Close Price`) over (order by `date` asc rows 19 preceding), 2) 
as '20 Day MA' 
from table1;
```

then read data with `select * from myview`

If you need a 'snapshot' of the table  you can 'materialize' with `select into`

```
CREATE TABLE my_new_table -- mysql syntax
select `Date`, `Close Price`,
round(avg(`Close Price`) over (order by `date` asc rows 19 preceding), 2) 
as '20 Day MA' 
-- into my_new_table --this forces the creation of new table -- sorry: SQL SERVER syntax
from table1
```

A third option is to add the new column than call an 'update' to populate it

Comment: What if the view has over 600 columns?

Answer (score 1):

To create a new table from a result set is straightforward. [CREATE ... SELECT is the way](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html).

```
 CREATE my_new_table AS
 SELECT whatever FROM sometable;
```

You need to give a valid column name (alias) for every column in your select.

**Pro tip:** Don't create tables where views will serve. When you use a view it gets the latest and greatest data from the underlying tables each time you use it. But when you create a table it's a snapshot in time.

**Pro tip:** Professors aren't pros, so they may give you exercises to complete that are bad ideas in the real world.

Comment: Hey, I just tried this (please see edit) but I get the error: Commands out of sync

Comment: Your table is corrupt. Do `REPAIR TABLE your_table_name`. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130019/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now  **Pro tip**: Use your favorite search engine to search for error messages, and you'll generally get something useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options:

- View: does not store data, every time it is queried, a query will run against the source tables
- "Materialized view": there is no such construct in MySQL, but you can emulate it with triggers on the source tables. If a row is created, updated or deleted, you can update the materialized view. Try to search for it, there are good descriptions about it.
  Useful if the source tables are rarely updated. May be a bit difficult if your `select` is complex.
- Temporary table: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (...);` and `INSERT INTO t1 SELECT (your query);`  (may be shortened to `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 AS SELECT (your query)`) . These tables create a snapshot of the current state, and live as long as your connection lives (even through transactions), but cannot be shared among connections. You can add indexes, etc, to speed up queries. It is useful if you have a complex process that needs to store data that are processed multiple times in the process.
- Create a column to store values, and create a MySQL `EVENT` to update it regularly.

IMHO since the 20 days moving average should be updated daily, the last solution is the best. If you don'tr trust MySQL, or have another job scheduler, you can call the updater SQL statement from there, too.